# Rampfunction code

Tags: python, math, signals

I'm trying to solve a problem:
create a function that reproduces rampfuntion

```
                     n, n >= 0  
               R(n)=
                     0, n < 0
```

Can someone help?

Comment: Can you show us what code you've written so far, and what results you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You gave a python tag, so I'll do it in python.

```
ramp = lambda x: x if x >= 0 else 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create it.

```
def R(n):
    try:
        if n >= 0:
            return n
        if n < 0:
            return 0
    except TypeError:
        pass
    # return None
```